# File.createTempFile() adding random strings to file name

Tags: android, android-image, android-image-capture

I am facing an issue which I do not understand. I am taking a picture then creating a PNG image file as per code that follows but somewhere down the line a random string is being added to the filename which causes me all sorts of issues. For example (as per tutorials I have found): I create an image called dimage_(generated timestamp) and save the string to shared preferences and the image in `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. In shared preferences the string is correct but the file has the above mentioned string appended.

Eg:
The generated filename string saved in shared prefs:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="driver_picture">dimage_20190610_065509</string>
</map>
```

Whereas the file checked with adb results as:

```
127|generic_x86:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/africa.mykagovehicledrivers/files/Pictures $ ls

dimage_20190610_0655091215099619.png

generic_x86:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/africa.mykagovehicledrivers/files    /Pictures $
```

I have no clue where the `1215099619` extra part comes from!

This is the code of the activity:

```
package africa.mykagovehicledrivers;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.yalantis.ucrop.UCrop;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class RegisterDriverImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    String currentPhotoPath;
    final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    final int CAMERA_PERMISSIONS = 3;
    Activity activity = this;

    ImageView imgTakePicture, imgDriver;
    Button btnContinueDriver;
    ProgressBar prgImage;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    String imageFileName;
    Tools t;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // All good so launch take picture from here
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            } else {
                // Permission denied. Warn the user and kick out of app
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.permsDeniedCameraTitle);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.permsDeniedCameraMessage);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finishAffinity();
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri starturi = Uri.fromFile(new File(currentPhotoPath));
            Uri destinationuri = Uri.fromFile(new File(currentPhotoPath));
            UCrop.Options options = AppConstants.setUcropOptions(activity);
            UCrop.of(starturi, destinationuri).withOptions(options).start(activity);
        }

        // On result from cropper add to image view

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            prgImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
            assert resultUri != null;
            File imgFile = new File(resultUri.getPath());
            Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            builder.build().load(imgFile).into(imgDriver, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d("-------->", "onSuccess: CROPPED!");
                    prgImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnContinueDriver.setEnabled(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_driver_image);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("mykago-driver", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit  = prefs.edit();
        imgTakePicture = findViewById(R.id.imgTakePicture);
        imgDriver = findViewById(R.id.imgDriver);
        btnContinueDriver = findViewById(R.id.btnContinueDriver);
        prgImage = findViewById(R.id.prgImage);

        t = new Tools(getApplication(), getApplicationContext(), this);

        imgTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });

        imgDriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });

        btnContinueDriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit.putString("driver_picture", imageFileName);
                edit.putString("nextstep", "drivinglicense");
                edit.apply();
                Intent drivinglicense = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterDrivingLicense.class);
                startActivity(drivinglicense);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Always ask for camera permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CAMERA }, CAMERA_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.d("IMAGE CREATION FAILED", ex.toString());
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "africa.mykagovehicledrivers.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        imageFileName = "dimage_" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".png",
                storageDir
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
}
```

As per code I am using `String imageFileName;` to save the path and then use it in the button click action to save it into shared preferences.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically, it does this because that is how it is designed / specified to work: see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-)  A temp file is one whose name is unlikely to be the same as another temp file.

Comment: Yes indeed, just found out. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reasin. createTempFile does this. Switched to new File() and this solved the issue.